# Why is Ubuntu 21.10 slow on my computer?

Tags: hardware

My PC has a nvme SSD,an Nvidia 1650 super, and 8 GB RAM, so I don't think any Operating System should run slow on my computer unless it's for hardware incompatibility. Is my hardware not fully supported by Ubuntu? or Ubuntu is a little slow? Slow as in when loading applications like file manager, browser etc.

Comment: Answering this question will be rather difficult without knowing more about your hardware, your definition of “slow”, and whether this pertains to every aspect of the system or just specific applications. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the brand and/or model of your computer (1) some more hardware specs (2) how long specific actions take (3) how long you expect them to take. With this, it will be possible for someone to ask more specific questions to narrow down any possible issue you might be experiencing 

Comment: Could you provide a your "self-definition" of "slow" please?. we can understand if u have some issues 'bout your hardware or may be a not-clean installation, but first you may start with these task.

Comment: Don't limit yourself to binary set of solutions "*Ubuntu must be slow*" or "*Ubuntu must not be compatible with my hardware*." Those are beginner mistakes. Some performance problems can be subtle to diagnose. Some may be due to obscure settings. Others can be due to user choices. It's a rich tapestry, so patience and an open mind are needed to diagnose successfully.